# Close position on specifc month day

Tags: r, quantstrat

I'm writting a strategy in R using quantstrat that needs to close any open position at the 15th day for every month.

I've already tried using `add.signal` with `sigTimespan`, but it seems it only works with time, and not dates. Maybe I'm not passing the right data format to the it's `timespan` argument. It asks for a POSIXct based object, so I wrote it like this:

```
add.signal(strategy = strategy,
           name = 'sigTimestamp',
           arguments = list(timestamp = as.POSIXct('2016-11-15 17:00:00'))
           label = 'timestamp')
```

... and it doesn't work. And even if it did, the signal would be useful only for closing that month's position.

A possible solution would be to place a delayed order to close the position at the same timespan it's opened by using the `delay` or `timespan` arguments, but I also couldn't manage to make it work. Here's what I've tried:

```
add.rule(strategy = strategy, name = 'ruleSignal', arguments =
            list(sigcol = 'long',
                 sigval = TRUE,
                 orderqty = 'all',
                 ordertype = 'market',
                 orderside = 'long',
                 replace = FALSE,
                 prefer = preferredPrice,
                 timestamp = as.POSIXct('2016-11-15 17:00:00')),
         type = 'exit', label = 'Timestamp Position Close')
```

Any thoughts?

I'm running R 3.3.2 and quantstrat 0.9.1739 under Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS with 5 minute data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a function that generates a trading signal at a specific timestamp and applied it on my OHLC data before calling quantstrat's `applyStrategy` function. That signal, together with an exit rule did the trick.

Comment: As I haven't yet found any quantstrat built-in solution, I'm marking this as the accepted answer for now.